# How to set tint in specific part of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Is there any way to set tint in specific part of image (say 1/4th part of the image) in ImageView . I want to name the images with TextView over ImageView but it is difficult to read the text over the images so i want to use tint the lower part of image with black with text(white color) over it .is there any way i can achieve that ??

Comment: using layout wight we can do it

Comment: you can set the background color of textview\

Comment: can we control the transparency of background color of textView ?

Comment: Yes you can use alpha or transparent color for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Relative layout which contains One Imageview and after ImageView a textview and then textview will come over imageview set the textview where you want on imageview, Also set the background of textview of colour you want and textcolor of textview which will be the write up color of textview item. Happy Coding

```
 ![<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/akash"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="akash jindal"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>][1]
```